# Lock a Select on the Postgres Database and updating the Column of "value+1" when necessary

Tags: php, postgresql, locking

I am updating this question, please do not mind the comments below as, instead of deleting this question, I reworked it to give it a sense.

A form on a php page let me create a csv file, to name this file I need to run a SELECT on the database, it the name does not exists, my query must create it; if the name exist, it must update it.

The problem is, there is a chance where 2 or more users can push the submit button at the same time.
This will cause the query to reurn the same value to all of them, therefore creating or updating the file in a non-controlled way.
I need to create a system, that will LOCK the table for INSERT/UPDATE and, if in the meantime another connection appear, the column on the database that will name the file must be incremented of +1.

```
$date = date("Ymd");
$csv = fopen("/tmp/$user_$date_$id_$reference.csv", 'w+');
```

Where "reference" is a progressive number in the format of "Axxxx". x's are numbers.

The SELECT would be:

```
$sql = pg_query($conn, " SELECT user, identification, reference, FROM orders WHERE identification = '$_POST[id_order]' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($sql)) {
    $user = $row[0];
    $id = $row[1];
    $reference = $row[2];
}
```

I need to create a function, like the one below, where users can both INSERT and UPDATE, and in the case of concurrent connection, the ones that are not the first will have "reference" incremented of 1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_identification( in_identification TEXT, in_user TEXT ) RETURNS void as $$
BEGIN
 UPDATE table SET identification=in_identification, user=in_user, reference=in_reference WHERE identification = in_identification;
 IF FOUND THEN 
  RETURN;
 END IF;
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO table ( identification, user, reference ) VALUES (in_identification, in_user, in_reference );
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  -- Should the increment be here?
 END;
RETURN;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I hope what I'm asking is clear, re-read and I do understand it. Please comment below for any question you might have.
I really hope someone can help me!

I was looking for some clues in the postgres manual, I found this link about locking but I am not so sure this is what I need: [LINK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html)

Comment: Are you considering locking your database table, or using Postgres as a lock in your application?

Comment: I'd just need locking the table, as long as I can achieve that I'm good. Problem is, if I lock the table only, others colleagues might constantly be not able to create this file, because the table is locked and there is not a queue system. Chance are poor, this should happen for 2 or more colleagues pushing the submit button at the same time. Still, it's a little chance, but there is. I'm looking for the best solution, anything that would guarantee me the system would not fail

Comment: ps. I need to calculate some latency due to VPN's and internet speed. I can not guarantee the system reacts fast for every request

Comment: Your intended approach is bad, and might not even work.  Instead, you should use a single record in the database, possibly the record corresponding to the order in question, as a resource lock.  Users who want to read the file can "check it out" by first acquiring this database lock.  Note that this would be a logical lock; once acquired, the database would be free to function as normal, except that anyone else trying to open the file would fail to obtain the lock.

Comment: I am not sure I understood it all, forgive me but it is a new territory for me. Locking the whole table is bad, but I can lock the column "reference", for example? Do you have a direct link or anything, where I can have a look at this, precisely? Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Locking columns is difficult or not possible.  I think you missed my point.  You need a _logical_ lock, not a table lock.

Comment: But why would you need a lock at all? Multiple simultaneous `SELECT` queries won't cause any race conditions at all. If you update the table in the meantime, that couldn't cause any race conditions either (at least with your reads; just use a transaction & select an appropriate [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) -- but the default should be enough). There is literally no benefit from disallowing multiple users executing your query.

Comment: I am confused now, I must not update the db. I need to run a SELECT which returns the really last element of that search. Reference is a progression number, say A00001. Users, when hit submit, will create the file *_A00002.csv. Then a java application will fetch this csv file and will update the DB with A00002. The next csv file will create a A00003 and again, the java will insert to the DB the A00003.
I need to lock, because I do not want users to create many A00003 csv file, but these file must progress (and most of the time the progression is A033982 -> A044112 (not incremental +1)

Comment: @pozs I think he wants to enforce that only one user at a time can "checkout" a certain CSV file.

Comment: A033982 -> A044112 (not incremental +1) *because the same java application will fetch others file and increment the reference again. Important is, that the csv generated is always +1 compared to the last in the database

Comment: @Nihvel Ok, so when the second user hits the submit (to create `..._A00003.csv` in your first example) did java finished processing of `A00002`? Your php script will create multiple csv files for the java process which will consume them all at once (some time possibly in the future)? -- **Or** you need to process `A00002` *before* the second user can generate `A00003`?

Comment: Yes java finished processing the A00002. There is a timer of 10 minutes, at the end of the counter an application will get all the csv generated and will process. After this process, the java is called. Java will fetch other file (xml) containing same entries and working on the same table. Java will update the Reference with a higher number. The csv for the next schedule will start from that number. It is a tricky system, I know, It is just how it is. I need to make sure that csv file generated are alwas +1

Comment: $name, $date.. all of them are columns. if there are 10 records in the column NAME (therefore date), php will generate 10 csv file, where the progression number may be the same, say A00001 for all of them. But the name and data will define which one is which. There is always 1, for each combination of name + date.